# ng-disabled not working in angular with django

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This is my angular form. ng-disabled is not working and i have tried with $pristine, $dirty and $touched. Also ng-submit is not working.I tried placing the button outside form but still its not working. Your suggestions will be appreciated. Please give some suggestions and i will get back to you if your inputs worked or not.

Thank you.

```
{% block content %}

<div class="container">

<form name="businessform" method="post" style="margin-top:5%;" ng-submit="Register">

  {% csrf_token %}
  {% verbatim %}

  <div ng-app="UserBusinessDataModule" ng-controller="UserBusinessDataModuleController" novalidate>

    <div>
      <h6>Business Name</h6>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" ng-value="data['name']" class="name" ng-model="name" ng-required="true"/>
    </div>

    <div>
      <h6>Address 1</h6>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" ng-value="data['address1']" class="address1"  ng-model="address1" ng-required="true"/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h6>Address 2</h6>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" ng-value="data['address2']" class="address2"  ng-model="address2" ng-required="true"/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h6>Zipcode</h6>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" ng-value="data['zipcode']" class="zipcode" ng-model="zipcode" ng-required="true"/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h6>City</h6>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" ng-value="data['city']" class="city" ng-model="city" ng-required="true"/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h6>State</h6>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" ng-value="data['state']" class="state" ng-model="state" ng-required="true"/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h6>industry</h6>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" ng-value="data['industry']" class="industry" ng-model="industry" ng-required="true"/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h6>Primary Business</h6>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" ng-value="data['primary_business']" class="primary_business" ng-model="primarybusiness" ng-required="true"/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h6>Secondary Business</h6>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" ng-value="data['secondary_business']" class="secondary_business" ng-model="secondarybusiness" ng-required="true"/>
    </div>

    <br>
    <button class="btn btn-success" value="submit" ng-disabled="businessform.$invalid"></button>
</div>

 {% endverbatim %}

</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is many changes need to be done.

1.**ng-app** and **ng-controller** div should be parent to the form element.Form element sould be inside div

2.Form element should contain **noValidate** attribute not div and **ng-submit sould** be function.

3.No need to use ng-value in input bind with ng-model only. For read only text use ng-value

4.In form submit button use attribute `type="submit"`. No need value attribute in button or use input `type=submit`

```js
angular.module('UserBusinessDataModule',[]).controller('UserBusinessDataModuleController',function($scope){
 
  $scope.data = {}
  
  $scope.register = function(){
    console.log($scope.data);
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="UserBusinessDataModule" ng-controller="UserBusinessDataModuleController">
<form name="businessform" style="margin-top:5%;" ng-submit="register()"  novalidate>
  <div>
    <div>
      <h6>Business Name</h6>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" class="name" ng-model="data.name" ng-required="true"/>
    </div>

    <div>
      <h6>Address 1</h6>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" class="address1"  ng-model="data.address1" ng-required="true"/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h6>Address 2</h6>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" class="address2"  ng-model="data.address2" ng-required="true"/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h6>Zipcode</h6>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" class="zipcode" ng-model="data.zipcode" ng-required="true"/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h6>City</h6>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" class="city" ng-model="data.city" ng-required="true"/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h6>State</h6>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" class="state" ng-model="data.state" ng-required="true"/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h6>industry</h6>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" class="industry" ng-model="data.industry" ng-required="true"/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h6>Primary Business</h6>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" class="primary_business" ng-model="data.primarybusiness" ng-required="true"/>
    </div>
    <div>
      <h6>Secondary Business</h6>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input type="text" class="secondary_business" ng-model="data.secondarybusiness" ng-required="true"/>
    </div>

    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="submit"  ng-disabled="businessform.$invalid" class="btn btn-success" />
  
</div>
</form>
</div>
```